# Generic class with contraint conforming to interface complains

Tags: c#, generics

Why doesn't this work? It complains `Generic<T>` does not implement interface member 'NormalInt.bsPro(LPP)'.
I also tried explicitly implementing the interface but still no luck!

```
class SomeType { }

interface NormalInt
{
    void bsPro(SomeType body);
}

class Generic<T>: NormalInt
    where T : SomeType
{

    public void bsPro(T body)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement this method from the interface.

`public void bsPro(SomeType body)`

Which specifically expects a `SomeType` instance in the params.

EDIT:

You need to make the interface generic, and then constrain the imlpementing class e.g.

```
public class SomeType
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}

public interface NormalInt<T>
{
    void bsPro(T body);
}

public class Generic<T> : NormalInt<T>
    where T : SomeType
{
    public void bsPro(T body)
    {
        body.Hello();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var g = new Generic<SomeType>();
        var s = new SomeType();

        g.bsPro(s);
    }
}
```

I believe the above should work for you.

Comment: Yeah but T is of type SomeType...whatever happened to polymorphism o_O

Comment: @schwarz This is not polymorphism, this is variance. `Dog` is a subtype of (polymorph with) `Animal`, but `List<Dog>` is not a subtype of `List<Animal>`.

Comment: @schwarz - That would not be safe since you could do `NormalInt i = new Generic<SomeSubType>(); i.bsPro(new SomeType())`, which would allow you to pass a `SomeType` to a method requiring a `SomeSubType`.

Comment: @Lee that was what I was looking for. Thanks...somehow I missed that :P